# Adjust touchscreen coordinates for 4:3 aspect ratio on a 16:10 screen

Tags: resolution, touch-screen

Hello I have kind of a weird device I've been working on lately. It is a tablet that has a native resolution of 800x1280 - yes it is backwards. The display is in portrait mode and I have to make some xorg config edits to rotate the screen and rotate the touchscreen. This works great if I use the native resolution, however I am trying to get it to use a 768x1024 resolution. I have succeeded in getting the 768x1024 resolution in 4:3 mode (with black bars on the side, which is what I want) to show on the tablet by using these commands:

```
user1:~ # xrandr --newmode "768x1024_60.00"   65.25  768 816 896 1024  1024 1027 1037 1063 -hsync +vsync
user1:~ # xrandr --addmode DSI-1 768x1024_60.00
user1:~ # xrandr -s 768x1024_60.00
```

What I'm having trouble with is getting the actual touchscreen digitizer to align with it, like it's still stuck in 16:10. Here are my xorg config files:

```
user1:~ # cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-touchscreen.conf
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "evdev touchscreen catchall"
        MatchIsTouchscreen "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "evdev"
        Option "SwapAxes" "true"
        Option "InvertY" "true"
EndSection

user1:~ # cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-monitor.conf
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "DSI-1"
    Option "Rotate" "right"
EndSection
```

Here are the properties of the touchscreen:

```
Device 'Goodix Capacitive TouchScreen':
    Device Enabled (152):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (154): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (284):     0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (285):       1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (286):       1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (287):    10.000000
    Device Product ID (276):        1046, 9111
    Device Node (275):      "/dev/input/event2"
    Evdev Axis Inversion (288):     0, 1
    Evdev Axis Calibration (289):   <no items>
    Evdev Axes Swap (290):  1
    Axis Labels (291):      "Abs MT Position X" (282), "Abs MT Position Y" (283), "Abs MT Touch Major" (280), "Abs MT Width Major" (281), "None" (0), "None" (0)
    Button Labels (292):    "Button Unknown" (277), "Button Unknown" (277), "Button Unknown" (277), "Button Wheel Up" (158), "Button Wheel Down" (159)
    Evdev Scrolling Distance (293): 0, 0, 0
    Evdev Middle Button Emulation (294):    0
    Evdev Middle Button Timeout (295):      50
    Evdev Third Button Emulation (296):     0
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (297):     1000
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (298):      3
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (299):   20
    Evdev Wheel Emulation (300):    0
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (301):       0, 0, 4, 5
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (302):    10
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (303):    200
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (304):     4
    Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (305):  0
    Evdev Kiosk Touch Mode (306):   0
    Evdev Kiosk Touch Button (307): 1
    Evdev Kiosk Touch Button Delay (308):   0
```

So is this a case where I need to edit the touch matrix? Any pointers on that or is there an easier way? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out using `xinput_calibrator`, which gave me the proper xorg calibration data.

Basically, open up a terminal window and start up the xinput_calibrator and touch the points it asks you to touch. After it finishes, the terminal window will spit out the information to use with xorg:

```
user1:~> xinput_calibrator
Calibrating EVDEV driver for "Goodix Capacitive TouchScreen" id=11
        current calibration values (from XInput): min_x=66, max_x=725 and min_y=-5, max_y=1284

Doing dynamic recalibration:
        Setting new calibration data: 61, 730, -3, 1272


--> Making the calibration permanent <--
  copy the snippet below into '/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-calibration.conf'
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier      "calibration"
        MatchProduct    "Goodix Capacitive TouchScreen"
        Option  "Calibration"   "61 730 -3 1272"
EndSection
```